# Are primitive types only types not inherited from java.lang.Object?

Tags: java, primitive-types

I'm reviewing the primitive types interview questions for a java role. I get asked such a statement during an test.

primitive type is any type that does not inherite from java.lang.Object.

Comment: Primitives are not objects and hence does not inherit from Java.lang.Object. However wrapper classes for primitives extends Object class. So they have methods which Object class has.

Comment: @VishalKamat while any user defined type is inherited from Object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are other types which do not extend `java.lang.Object`. For example, `null` is a value, so it does not extend it. Interfaces do not extend it either, though abstract class do.

About primitive types, the answer is yes and no. When you write them, primitive type do not inherit from `java.lang.Object`. However, when compiling your java code to java bytecode, the compiler does something called [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

In short, at compile time the compiler transforms all the primitive values into their wrapper class (`Integer` for int, `Boolean` for boolean, etc). However, he does that efficiently, because it transforms `int i = 0;` into `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(0);`. Behind the scenes, the `valueOf` function of wrapper types is a Flyweight Factory, that is there is at most one instance of the Integer 0, one of the Integer 1, etc...

So, when coding you work with primitive types, but the JVM works with the wrapper of the primitive types, which implement `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 2):

No they are not. Interfaces also do not inherit from `java.lang.Object`

Comment: null is not either, they ask about type.